# Where has the content from my HTML Input-File disappeared to?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

Trying to import some string from file via HTML FileReader begins to be painful for me. Due testing, alert inside the main function shows content which disappeared after event is done.
Please enlighten me.

```
<input type="file" id="Open" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function readSingleFile(evt) {
  var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
  var r = new FileReader();
  var contents;
  if (f) {
      r.onloadend = function(evt) { 
        var contents = evt.target.result.substr();
        // this alert show string content
        alert(contents);
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
  }
  // there's no string content - (undefined)
  alert(contents);
}
document.getElementById('Open').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FileReader` object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files.
You can not get file contents immediately after call r.readAsText(f)
You should deal contents in `onloadend` `evt` function

Just like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contents;

    function readSingleFile(evt) {
      var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
      var r = new FileReader();

      if (f) {
          r.onloadend = function(evt) { 
            contents = evt.target.result.substr();
            // this alert show string content
            alert(contents);

            //code for the contents
          }
          r.readAsText(f);
      }
      // there's no string content - (undefined)
      //alert(contents);
    }
    document.getElementById('Open').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Now I can call "contents" from another function with some button click. But I need to proceed with "contents" data in next function continuously? Calling next function from the end of first won't work.